# Reading and executing formulas from text

Tags: excel

I have a problem where I have a need to execute a complex formula saved as text.
I can only find VBA and EVAL() solutions, which cannot be used in my situation.

For example, I have a cell with:

```
IF(VLOOKUP($A1;Summary!$E:$K;1;TRUE)=$A1;VLOOKUP($A1;Summary!$E:$K;7;TRUE);0)
```

and I would like a formula in another cell to have the result obtained when running the example formula.
I get a #REF! error when trying INDIRECT()

Edit: Basically, is there a way to run EVALUATE() formula without defining your own formula through "Name manager" that does just that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to display the result right to the right of the formula text.
Suppose the formulatext is in cell A2.

1. Select cell B2
2. Control+F3, Add
3. Name: EvalFormula
4. RefersTo: =EVALUATE(A2)
5. OK your way out
6. in B2 enter =EvalFormula

Comment: This works in usual Excel, thanks.

My problem is that I am working in another system based on Excel and that user defined EvalFormula is deleted when saving the workbook

Comment: Now you tell us :-)